# I Try Call Win32 API WriteConsoleOutputA use NASM

Tags: winapi, assembly, nasm

i try call WriteConsoleOutputA use NASM

but the error message always display

87 (0x57)

The parameter is incorrect.

i don't know how to solve this problem

```
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE   EQU -11
NULL                EQU 0

GLOBAL GobleyGook
EXTERN ExitProcess, GetLastError, GetStdHandle, WriteConsoleA, WriteConsoleOutputA, FormatMessageA

SECTION .data

STRUC lpBuffer
    .Char      : RESW 1
    .Attributes: RESD 1
ENDSTRUC

_lpBuffer ISTRUC lpBuffer
    at lpBuffer.Char, DW 'A'
    at lpBuffer.Attributes, DD 1H
IEND

STRUC dwBufferSize
    .X: RESW  1 
    .Y: RESW  1
ENDSTRUC

_dwBufferSize ISTRUC dwBufferSize
    at dwBufferSize.X, DW 10
    at dwBufferSize.Y, DW 10
IEND

STRUC dwBufferCoord
    .X: RESW 1
    .Y: RESW 1
ENDSTRUC

_dwBufferCoord ISTRUC dwBufferCoord
    at dwBufferCoord.X, DW 0
    at dwBufferCoord.Y, DW 0
IEND

STRUC smallRect
    .Left  : RESW 1
    .Top   : RESW 1
    .Right : RESW 1
    .Bottom: RESW 1
ENDSTRUC

_smallRect ISTRUC smallRect
IEND

SECTION .bss
dummy   RESD 1
err     RESD 1
err2    RESD 1

SECTION .text
GobleyGook: 
    PUSH    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    CALL    GetStdHandle

    PUSH    _smallRect
    PUSH    _dwBufferCoord
    PUSH    _dwBufferSize
    PUSH    _lpBuffer
    PUSH    EAX
    CALL    WriteConsoleOutputA

    CALL    GetLastError

    PUSH    NULL
    PUSH    99
    PUSH    err
    PUSH    NULL
    PUSH    EAX
    PUSH    NULL
    PUSH    1000H
    CALL    FormatMessageA

    PUSH    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    CALL    GetStdHandle

    push    NULL
    push    dummy
    push    32
    push    err
    push    EAX
    call    WriteConsoleA

    PUSH    NULL
    CALL    ExitProcess
```

Link & compiler

```
nasm -f win32 print.asm
golink.exe /console /entry GobleyGook print.obj kernel32.dll
```

on the windows 8.1 64bit

The API document

https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/ms687404(v=vs.85).aspx

please help me....

Comment: I'm wondering if you need to pass the coordinate parameters as a `DWORD` instead of as a pointer to a structure; if that is the case, I don't fully know why (I just know it's needed for some structures, like `BLENDFUNCTION`).

Comment: I concur with @andlabs.  The documentation shows both `dwBufferSize` and `dwBufferCoord` passed by value, not via a pointer.

Comment: i try direct push 10(size) and push 0(Coord)，display same error message...

Comment: Have you tried looking at C compiler output for making the same function call?

Comment: yes, i tried the C++ version...that is success

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just modify your code as below, it will work!

```
PUSH    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
CALL    GetStdHandle

PUSH    _smallRect
mov ecx, [_dwBufferCoord]
PUSH    ecx
mov edx, [_dwBufferSize]
PUSH   edx 
PUSH    _lpBuffer
PUSH    EAX
CALL    WriteConsoleOutputA
```

Answer (score 2):

You make several mistakes in your code:

- As pointed out in the comments you need to pass the `COORD` parameters by value
- You need to pass a `dwBufferSize` value that is equal the size of your buffer
- You need to pass a `lpWriteRegion` structure (by reference) that is initialized with the coordinates of where you want the buffer displayed on screen.
- You need to check the return value of `WriteConsoleOutputA` to determine whether it failed. You can't reliably use `GetLastError` to determine if it failed.
- Your definition of your `lpBuffer` structure is incorrect. The second member `Attributes` of the corresponding `CHAR_INFO` structure is a 16-bit `WORD` not a 32-bit `DWORD`.

Your buffer is only a single character making it a 1x1 buffer, but you're trying to pass a buffer size of 10x10. Since you don't initialize `_smallRect` its value is 0,0,0,0 which puts the output at the top left corner of the console buffer.  The means your single character output is probably going to immediately scroll off the screen when your program finishes and the command prompt is printed and you'll never see it.

Here's a version of your program with all these problems fixed:

```
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE   EQU -11
NULL                EQU 0

GLOBAL GobleyGook
EXTERN _ExitProcess@4, _GetLastError@0, _GetStdHandle@4, _WriteConsoleA@20, _WriteConsoleOutputA@20, _FormatMessageA@28

SECTION .data

STRUC lpBuffer
    .Char      : RESW 1
    .Attributes: RESW 1
ENDSTRUC

_lpBuffer ISTRUC lpBuffer
    at lpBuffer.Char, DW 'A'
    at lpBuffer.Attributes, DW 2H | 8H
IEND

STRUC smallRect
    .Left  : RESW 1
    .Top   : RESW 1
    .Right : RESW 1
    .Bottom: RESW 1
ENDSTRUC

_smallRect ISTRUC smallRect
    at smallRect.Left, DW 40
    at smallRect.Top, DW 12
    at smallRect.Right, DW 41
    at smallRect.Bottom, DW 13
IEND

SECTION .bss
dummy   RESD 1
err     RESD 1
err2    RESD 1

SECTION .text
GobleyGook: 
    PUSH    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    CALL    _GetStdHandle@4

    PUSH    _smallRect
    PUSH    (0 << 16) | 0  ; dwBufferCoord = 0,0
    PUSH    (1 << 16) | 1  ; dwBufferSize  = 1,1
    PUSH    _lpBuffer
    PUSH    EAX
    CALL    _WriteConsoleOutputA@20

    cmp     eax, 0
    jnz     .exit

    CALL    _GetLastError@0

    PUSH    NULL
    PUSH    99
    PUSH    err
    PUSH    NULL
    PUSH    EAX
    PUSH    NULL
    PUSH    1000H
    CALL    _FormatMessageA@28

    PUSH    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    CALL    _GetStdHandle@4

    push    NULL
    push    dummy
    push    32
    push    err
    push    EAX
    call    _WriteConsoleA@20

.exit:
    PUSH    0
    CALL _ExitProcess@4
```

I've changed your program so it displays the single character buffer at 40,12 and made it bright green instead of dark blue so it shows up better on the black background.  I've also changed the names of API functions to their actual assembly names so it would link with the Microsoft linker.

Comment: thk for your help~ but @Sam Shaw first solve my problem, You are right, the Attributes is word not dword

Comment: if i success call the function, the GetLastError will return success message

Comment: @Michael No, as I said you can't depend on that. As the documentation for `GetLastError` says "some functions set the last-error code to 0 on success and others do not.".  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx